# Java Swing or SWT: easy way to build a desktop UI "wizard" -- suggestions?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, swt

I'm an experienced Java programmer.  Used to do a lot of Swing by hand with Eclipse, but been mostly into web stuff for the past couple years.

I have to build a desktop UI, a kind of wizard-y thing, choosing items from lists, typing in fields, next...next...next... that sort of thing.

Before I jump into building it by hand with Swing, I'm wondering if there's been any major developments in the Java world with regards to desktop UIs.  Is there something I should look at, maybe a drag-and-drop UI builder, or some kind of framework, that will make it easier?

Any advice is useful, thanks!
Rob

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another option is to use the IWizard framework in Eclipse RCP, which works pretty well and is built for exactly what you're trying to do.  I'd recommend coding it by hand if you choose this option, as window builder probably won't make your life easier in the long run.  Of course, if you're a lot more comfortable with Swing already, you could just stick to that.

Comment: thanks, that's very useful because the thing i'm building could work well as an eclipse plug in.

Answer (score 4):

See [WindowBuilder](http://www.eclipse.org/windowbuilder/). It can build Swing or SWT GUI. WindowBuilder used to be a very profitable product of a company called Instantiations. Then Google bought the company and donated WindowBuilder to OSS community. It is now an eclipse.org project with many of the original developers contributing to it.

Answer (score 3):

[NetBeans](http://netbeans.org/) has a really powerful and easy-to-use Swing GUI builder that comes with it.

Comment: thanks, do you happen to know if it can build SWT UIs as well?

Comment: You can probably build SWT applications in NetBeans, but the GUI builder is Swing based (as far as I know).

Comment: @Robert, no SWT is not supported by Netbeans, you would need Eclipse for SWT work.

Comment: If you have a chance to move from Swing to SWT, take it. The results aren't comparable as SWT uses native widgets. All the bad rap that Java got on the desktop is due to Swing.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest sticking to hand coding with Swing.  The NetBeans editor has improved in the last couple of years, but still generates code that is not easily read by humans or easily modified by hand.

There are some third party libraries that do have some wizard like components that you might be able to make use of.

Comment: Thanks.  Can you suggest any specific 3rd party "wizard"-like libraries?

Comment: I think SwingLabs has one, but most of the documentation is temporarly lost in the move to java.net.  Here a tool that I have not used but looks promising: http://code.google.com/p/cjwizard/

Comment: How is it not readable? I tried a few Swing projects using netbeans, and the code was very readable, more so than the code written by a few humans I know

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Windowbuilder Pro](http://code.google.com/javadevtools/wbpro/index.html). You can create GUIs in both Swing and SWT. And GWT, if you want to.